# Efficient algorithm for edit distance for short sequences

Tags: strings, edit-distance

I have an application that needs to compute billions of levenshtein distance between pairs of strings. The strings are short (70 in length) DNA sequences, consisting only of 4 characters. Also it can be assumed that one of the strings is fixed, i.e., we are comparing one fixed string to a billion other strings.

I know that the dynamic programming implementation of the levenshtein distance is $\mathcal{O}(m n)$, would like to know if there are any room for improvement. I found these two algorithms:

- $\mathcal{O}(n + d^2)$ algorithm, in which $d$ is the edit distance by  [Berghel et al](http://www.berghel.net/publications/asm/asm.php). However I can't make the assumption that $d$ is small so it might not give any advantage
- $log(n)^{\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon)}$  approximation in $n^{1+\epsilon}$ time by [Andoni et al](https://onak.pl/papers/focs_2010-approximating_edit_distance.html). But I have two concerns regarding this:

  - Is this algorithm also fast in practice?
  - Does $log(n)^{\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon)}$ mean the computed edit distance in worst case is $log(n)^{\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon)}$ times the actual one? In that case it's too much.

Do you know of any other algorithm/idea/approach that might be applicable?

Comment: Have you looked at Levenshtein automata?

Comment: Does it have to be exactly the Levenshtein distance, or is any relatively consistent edit distance good enough?

Comment: Are you only interested in the edit distance if the edit distance is below some threshold (e.g., if the edit distance is $> 20$, you don't care what the exact edit distance is; just know that it is $> 20$ suffices)?

Comment: Is DNA really Levenshtein similar.  11 versus 00 is 2 for Levenshtein but 10 versus 01 is only 1.    I would be really surprised with DNA a match or not is all that matters.

Comment: @PålGD a good approximation of the Levenshtein distance could also be good.

Comment: @D.W. I am actually interested in short distances only. So if the two strings are $D>20$ apart I don't need to compute it precisely but if they're close I want the distance

Comment: @AmeerJewdaki did you find a suitable solution? I've toyed around with Levenshtein and searching through larger datasets here https://github.com/prinzhorn/nicenshtein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to build a [Levenshtein automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton) for the fixed string (see, e.g., [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata)).  Given a string $x$ and a distance $D$, you can build a DFA that recognizes all strings that are at distance $\le D$ from $x$.  Thus, you can test whether a string is close to $x$ in $O(n)$ time, where $n$ is the length of the string.  I'm not sure what the space requirements are to store the DFA (they are linear in $m,n$, but might be exponential in $D$).

Alternatively, you could use an "early-out" algorithm for computing the edit distance.  You mentioned that you are only interested in the edit distance if it is less than some threshold $D$.  There is an "early-out" algorithm for computing the edit distance whose running time is $O(\max(n,m) \times D)$, which computes the edit distance if it is $\le D$ or else outputs "too big" if it is $>D$.  Basically, you do the standard dynamic programming algorithm for the edit distance, but only compute the elements of the matrix that are $\le D$ away from the diagonal.  In your case this might or might not be better than the other alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to do billions and it was only 4 characters I would represent the characters as
1000
0100
0010
0001
It is then a 35 byte integer

Dot a bit-wise `and` and count the 1's

Not perfect but billions is a lot unless you throw a lot of CPU at it.

Comment: It's actually some trillions of distance calls in total, but I have access to a computing cluster. 
The problem is that if two strings are 100 in length and there are several  insertions or deletions the dot product will deviate from the actual distance.

Comment: OK you said 70 in Length.  I am surprised an algorithm based on words applies to DNA.  The are scientific DNA matching equations - I am surprised you are not using one of those.

Comment: Not complaining but a DV does not help me be a better contributor here.

Comment: I didn't down vote the answer. In fact I think it's generally a good approach, but here it is too far off because of insertions/deletions.

Comment: and yes there are probabilistic ways to define distance between two DNA sequences but none, I believe, is simpler to compute than edit distance. So here I'm just starting with the "simple" measure

Comment: I don't want to argue but is there any basis the "simple" has any scientific basis.   A word and DNA are not the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62921/discussion-between-ameer-jewdaki-and-paparazzi).

Comment: For getting the *count of characters differing*, one-hot encoding and pop-count does look smart.